# Excel Vlookup Error for Some of My Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have an Excel report with web page titles that I am trying to match corresponding page views to using VLOOKUP.  The lookup table is a separate Excel file exported from Google Analytics.

When I perform VLOOKUP, it works for some of the cells, but there are plenty that have an N/A even though, when I go to the Google Analytics spread sheet, the matching page title is there along with its page views.  Could punctuation in page titles be causing the errors?  I noticed that most of the titles that I get N/A for either contain an apostrophe, semi colon, dash or some other punctuation that Excel may not recognize.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Generált punctuation characters don't cause problem in excel, please post some data which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data that shows the problem. See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be using Fuzzy Lookup, a tool distributed by Microsoft which provides the ability to match between inexact items. It will provide you with a % "match" or "confidence", giving you most of the matches that you'd consider "close enough".

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

This is a good video that explains how to use it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v-qxcjZbyo

However if you find&replace all the erroneous characters out, make sure you sort your data alphabetically for VLOOKUP to function properly, and lock your table references with dollar signs before you pull it down: `$R$C`

Comment: For the sake of improvement, can you please offer an explanation of what "Fuzzy Lookup" is and how it it the correct answer.